# Padding Labels for Tensorflow CTC Loss?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to pad my labels so that they would be of equal length to be passed into the ctc_loss function. Apparently, -1 is not allowed. If I were to apply padding, should the padding value be part of the labels for ctc?

**Update**

I have this code that converts dense labels into sparse ones to be passed to the ctc_loss function which I think is related to the problem.

```
def dense_to_sparse(dense_tensor, out_type):
    indices = tf.where(tf.not_equal(dense_tensor, tf.constant(0, dense_tensor.dtype)
    values = tf.gather_nd(dense_tensor, indices)
    shape = tf.shape(dense_tensor, out_type=out_type)
    return tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowed"? I use -1 as padding just fine. The labels need to be passed into the ctc_loss as a sparse tensor anyway, and this sparse tensor should not contain any padding.

Comment: ctc throws this error when I put -1 as padding: `All labels must be nonnegative integers`. Say I have a target label "apple" and the encoding for it is [0, 15, 15, 12, 5]. If I add -1 as padding like so [0, 15, 15, 12, 5, -1, -1, -1], I encounter that error.

Comment: why do you want to pad your ground truth texts? You specify the length of each text via the indices and values of your sparse tensor anyway. The sparse tensor interface of course is pretty complex in my opinion, however, it just transfers your label strings to the op. The label string entries must correspond to the indices of the RNN output (matrix), therefore they must be between 0 and the index of the blank minus 1.

Comment: See my answer; let me know if that helps.

Comment: instead of feeding a dense tensor and then mapping it to a sparse tensor inside the TF graph, I just feed a sparse tensor. Therefore, I can avoid the padding completely.

Comment: @Harry, one reason I’d like to feed a dense tensor and do the conversion within the graph is that I’m using Tensorflow estimators and apparently, estimators don’t accept SparseTensors as labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it. I have a dense tensor `labels` that includes padding with -1, so that all targets in a batch have the same length. Then I use

```
labels_sparse = dense_to_sparse(labels, sparse_val=-1)
```

where

```
def dense_to_sparse(dense_tensor, sparse_val=0):
    """Inverse of tf.sparse_to_dense.

    Parameters:
        dense_tensor: The dense tensor. Duh.
        sparse_val: The value to "ignore": Occurrences of this value in the
                    dense tensor will not be represented in the sparse tensor.
                    NOTE: When/if later restoring this to a dense tensor, you
                    will probably want to choose this as the default value.
    Returns:
        SparseTensor equivalent to the dense input.
    """
    with tf.name_scope("dense_to_sparse"):
        sparse_inds = tf.where(tf.not_equal(dense_tensor, sparse_val),
                               name="sparse_inds")
        sparse_vals = tf.gather_nd(dense_tensor, sparse_inds,
                                   name="sparse_vals")
        dense_shape = tf.shape(dense_tensor, name="dense_shape",
                               out_type=tf.int64)
        return tf.SparseTensor(sparse_inds, sparse_vals, dense_shape)
```

This creates a sparse tensor of the labels, which is what you need to put into the ctc loss. That is, you call `tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=labels_sparse, ...)` The padding (i.e. all values equal to -1 in the dense tensor) is simply not represented in this sparse tensor.

Comment: It did work. I just have something to clarify. What do you mean by "When/if later restoring this to a dense tensor, you will probably want to choose this as the default value"? Should I use 0 to restore it to a dense tensor?

Comment: What I mean is: The `tf.sparse_to_dense` function has a `default_value`argument. You will probably want to pick -1 for that argument (so that the restored dense tensor once again uses -1 as padding/filler). Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `-1` values are allowed to be present in the `y_true` argument of the [ctc_batch_cost](https://keras.io/backend/#ctc_batch_cost) with one limitation - they should not appear within the actual label "content" which is specified by `label_length` (here `i`-th label  "content" would start from the index `0` and end at the index `label_length[i]`).

So it is perfectly fine to pad labels with `-1` so that they would be of equal length, as you intended. The only thing you should take care about is to correctly calculate and pass corresponding `label_length` values.

Here is the sample code which is a modified version of the `test_ctc` [unit test from keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/cb96315a291a8515544c6dd807500073958f8928/tests/keras/backend/backend_test.py#L1709):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

number_of_categories = 4
number_of_timesteps = 5

labels = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, -1]])
label_lens = np.expand_dims(np.asarray([5, 4]), 1)

# dimensions are batch x time x categories
inputs = np.zeros((2, number_of_timesteps, number_of_categories), dtype=np.float32)
input_lens = np.expand_dims(np.asarray([5, 5]), 1)

k_labels = K.variable(labels, dtype="int32")
k_inputs = K.variable(inputs, dtype="float32")
k_input_lens = K.variable(input_lens, dtype="int32")
k_label_lens = K.variable(label_lens, dtype="int32")

res = K.eval(K.ctc_batch_cost(k_labels, k_inputs, k_input_lens, k_label_lens))
```

It runs perfectly fine even with `-1` as the last element of the (second) `labels` sequence because corresponding `label_lens` item (second) specified that its length is 4.

If we change it to be 5 or if we change some other label value to be `-1` then we have the `All labels must be nonnegative integers` exception that you've mentioned. But this just means that our `label_lens` is invalid.